# Returning status of columns based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (refer to the last part for the dictionary if you have trouble with the tables/dataframes):

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  term_months contract_type   renewal_type    2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-06-01 00:00:00
0   1   A   2020-12-20  1   Original    Regular 200.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   1   B   2020-12-25  12  Upgrade Regular 300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   1   C   2021-03-06  12  Upgrade Early   0.0 0.0 0.0 400.0   400.0   0.0 0.0
3   2   K   2020-12-01  4   Original    Regular 100.0   100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   2   F   2021-02-23  6   Renewal Early   0.0 0.0 50.0    50.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
5   3   Z   2020-12-01  12  Original    Regular 80.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
6   3   Y   2021-01-20  12  Upgrade Early   0.0 90.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I want the following output:

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  term_months contract_type   renewal_type    Status  2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-06-01 00:00:00
0   1   A   2020-12-20  1   Original    Regular Inactive    200.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   1   B   2020-12-25  12  Upgrade Regular Active  300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   1   C   2021-03-06  12  Upgrade Early   Active  0.0 0.0 0.0 400.0   400.0   0.0 0.0
3   2   K   2020-12-01  4   Original    Regular Inactive    100.0   100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   2   F   2021-02-23  6   Renewal Early   Active  0.0 0.0 50.0    50.0    0.0 0.0 0.0
5   3   Z   2020-12-01  12  Original    Regular Inactive    80.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
6   3   Y   2021-01-20  12  Upgrade Early   Inactive    0.0 90.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Each account can have multiple contracts. The status depends on term of the contract and the current date set (in this example, it's May 2021). Also, if there are no payments after 4 months (4-month rule), it will be considered as "Inactive". The exception for this four-month rule is that if the next contract has "Early" as its renewal type and there are still payments (meaning, the next "Early" contract did not violate the four-month rule).

Here's the dictionary for the dataframe:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3},
 'contract_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'K', 4: 'F', 5: 'Z', 6: 'Y'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-20 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-12-25 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-02-23 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-01-20 00:00:00')},
 'term_months': {0: 1, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 4, 4: 6, 5: 12, 6: 12},
 'contract_type': {0: 'Original',
  1: 'Upgrade',
  2: 'Upgrade',
  3: 'Original',
  4: 'Renewal',
  5: 'Original',
  6: 'Upgrade'},
 'renewal_type': {0: 'Regular',
  1: 'Regular',
  2: 'Early',
  3: 'Regular',
  4: 'Early',
  5: 'Regular',
  6: 'Early'},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 200.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 80.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 90.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 50.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0}}
```

Here's the dictionary for the result:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3},
 'contract_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'K', 4: 'F', 5: 'Z', 6: 'Y'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-20 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-12-25 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-02-23 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-01-20 00:00:00')},
 'term_months': {0: 1, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 4, 4: 6, 5: 12, 6: 12},
 'contract_type': {0: 'Original',
  1: 'Upgrade',
  2: 'Upgrade',
  3: 'Original',
  4: 'Renewal',
  5: 'Original',
  6: 'Upgrade'},
 'renewal_type': {0: 'Regular',
  1: 'Regular',
  2: 'Early',
  3: 'Regular',
  4: 'Early',
  5: 'Regular',
  6: 'Early'},
 'Status': {0: 'Inactive',
  1: 'Active',
  2: 'Active',
  3: 'Inactive',
  4: 'Active',
  5: 'Inactive',
  6: 'Inactive'},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 200.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 80.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 90.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 50.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0}}
```

Comment: If one account can have multiple contracts, have you tried splitting a cell to get to 2 contracts in one column? https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-split-a-pandas-dataframe-column-in-python is a resource for doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by your question?

Comment: Are you specifying the date May 2021 as an external variable or is this May 2021 data because the last column is "2021-06-01"?

Comment: Yes, May 2021 or May 1, 2021 is an external variable.

Comment: Why is `3,2,K,2020-12-01,4,Original,Regular` inactive when both the next contract is Early and it has payments within the last 4 months? Also `5,3,Z,2020-12-01,12,Original,Regular` is Inactive, but the next contract is early?

Comment: For 3,2,K,2020-12-01,4,Original,Regular , it is because it has only a term of 4 months. The term of the contract will prevail over the "Early" condition of the next contract. For 5,3,Z,2020-12-01,12,Original,Regular , it is because the contract with "Early" is also inactive given that it has not paid for four months already.